# How to deploy Django 3.2 App in AWS EBS with a Python VENV

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-venv

I've written a Django application and I want to deploy it to Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk.

To deploy it, I use the following command: `eb create bizkaimove-server-2-env`

But it fails when it comes to deploy it, here:

(cfn-init-cmd.log)

```
2022-02-18 09:36:33,838 P3272 [INFO] Command pip_upgrade
2022-02-18 09:36:33,841 P3272 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2022-02-18 09:36:33,841 P3272 [INFO]    /bin/sh: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip: No such file or directory
2022-02-18 09:36:33,841 P3272 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
2022-02-18 09:36:33,842 P3272 [ERROR] Exited with error code 127
```

I've created a virtual environment to run it locally, but I don't know whether this venv is run within the EBS. But it seems it's.

To sum up, my app is written using Django 3.2, Python 3.9 and it depends on a PostgreSQL database (remote, not embedded) and GDAL installation.

My folder structure is the following:

```
bizkaimove_server
  |- .ebsextensions
    |- 00-django.config
    |- 01-gdal.config
    |- 02-upgrade_pip.config
    |- 03-install_dependencies.config
    |- 04-django-contrab.config
  |- .elasticbeanstalk
    |- config.yml
  |- env_bizkaimove (python virtual environment folder)
  |- requirements.txt
```

The content of the files are:

00-django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: bizkaimove_server.wsgi:application
```

01-gdal.config

```
commands:
  01_install_gdal:
    test: "[ ! -d /usr/local/gdal ]"
    command: "/tmp/gdal_install.sh"
files:
  "/tmp/gdal_install.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
      sudo yum -y install make automake gcc gcc-c++ libcurl-devel proj-devel geos-devel

      # Geos
      cd /
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/geos
      cd usr/local/geos/geos-3.9.2
      sudo wget geos-3.9.2.tar.bz2 http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.9.2.tar.bz2
      sudo tar -xvf geos-3.9.2.tar.bz2
      cd geos-3.9.2
      sudo ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo make install
      sudo ldconfig

      # Proj4
      cd /
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/proj
      cd usr/local/proj
      sudo wget -O proj-8.2.1.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-8.2.1.tar.gz
      sudo wget -O proj-datumgrid-1.8.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-1.8.tar.gz
      sudo tar xvf proj-8.2.1.tar.gz
      sudo tar xvf proj-datumgrid-1.8.tar.gz
      cd proj-8.2.1
      sudo ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo make install
      sudo ldconfig

      # GDAL
      cd /
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/gdal
      cd usr/local/gdal
      sudo wget -O gdal-3.4.1.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.4.1/gdal-3.4.1.tar.gz
      sudo tar xvf gdal-3.4.1.tar.gz
      cd gdal-3.4.1
      sudo ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo make install
      sudo ldconfig
```

02-upgrade_pip.config

```
commands:
  pip_upgrade:
    command: /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
    ignoreErrors: false
```

03-install_dependencies.config

```
commands:
  install_dependencies:
    command: /usr/local/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

04-django-contrab.config (no need to show its details here.)

config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: bizkaimove-server-2-env
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  bizkaimove-server-2-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
  bizkaimove-server-2-env2:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: bizkaimove-server-2-app
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: *****
  default_platform: Python 3.8
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

Why am I getting that error when it comes to upgrade pip? I feel that I'm missing some step to activate venv. But I wouldn't like to make use of venv here, since that venv is would be only for testing purposes locally (there's no point in using it in production since we've an instance of python).

Answer (score 1):

the Django application with python platform is deployed in the virtual environment and you don't have to activate the virtual environment, it will get activated by itself.

Second, you don't have to provide the command to install the requirements.txt file. The Elastic Beanstalk python platform is designed in a way to install all the packages that are mentioned requirements.txt

Third, I think you WSGI wath is not configured correctly. You have mentioned -

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: bizkaimove_server.wsgi:application
```

But it should be the path to the WSGI file which marks the start of application. According to your directory structure, I am assuming the WSGI file is in directory "env_bizkaimove". So the correct path would be -

```
option_settings:
      aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
        WSGIPath: env_bizkaimove.wsgi:application
```

In AL1 type platform,by default at port 80 apache runs which listens the request and forwards them to the virtual host at port 80 using WSGI.

In AL2, nginx web server runs by default with all the platforms which listens on port 80 and forwards the request to port 8000.

Plus, the pip update command in the virtual env need correction as well.

If you are using AL1, then it should be -

```
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

And if you are using AL2, then it should be -

```
/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

You can read more about how to deploy a Django App here on Beanstalk here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Comment: I've got the following error: `/bin/sh: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip: No such file or directory`

Comment: You are using AL2 platform I believe which uses Amazon Linux 2. You should try this command - `/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Yes, I've written it correctly. I'm starting to think that `.ebextensions` directory isn't getting caught by eb...

Comment: You can find this path in the environment variable section of the environment as well (You can check this in software configurations). It will show the exact path for virtual env based upon your selection. if you can provide the name of the solution stack that you are using, it might help in narrowing the issue down.